# Modem restart script with php

Tags: php, curl, modem

I'm creating a script to restart the modem for get a new IP. I did it with c# form application successfully. Now I'm trying to do it with php curl. But it gives me error.

```
$post = 'redirect=&user=admin&password=111111&button=OK';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.2.1/cgi-bin/login');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'modem.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  'modem.txt');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$http = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
curl_close($ch);
```

When I execute this, it redirects to http://localhost/main.html and says;

"Not Found

The requested URL /main.html was not found on this server."

Comment: That's not a problem in your code; that's your code not even being installed on the server, at least not in the place you expect it to be.  Is your code actually in a file called `main.html` (and not, say, `main.php`)?  Is that file located in the server's document root?

Comment: @Wyzard I think modem interface is trying to redirect the curl to http://192.168.2.1/main.html page.

Comment: Does it matter where the redirect points to? If the login is successful and stored in the cookie, it doesn't matter where you get redirected or if you get a 404 there. Just make your next request.

Comment: Your POST formdata has `redirect=` in it. Is this correct? It is also strange that the `192.168.2.1` host is sending a redirect to `localhost`. These may be related.

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Yes the original request that I captured with tamper data has redirect= 
I'm executing the script on http://localhost/modemrestart.php Maybe it is why is redirects to localhost.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider It won't store the cookies because I think it gives cookies after 2-3 redirects. But the first redirect goes to http://localhost/main.html and gives error. That's what I couldn't figure out. Also changing the $post = 'redirect= didn't work.

Comment: Your best bet would be to inspect the http requests / responses and see what is giving you a Location header back to localhost. I assume that the /cgi-bin/login form only handles the login part. Don't you have to then make a request to some restart page?

Comment: `$post = 'POST_DATA=<xmlrequest version=\"1.0.0\"><command inst=\"pppox-0\"><key>apply</key><value/></command></xmlrequest>';


$ch2 = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://192.168.2.1/cgi-bin/webapp');
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "modem.txt");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR,  "modem.txt");
curl_setopt($ch2, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$response = curl_exec($ch2);`

Comment: @JoshTriiJohnston Yes. On my c# application, I'm sending another post request to webbrowser. 

To the `http://192.168.2.1/cgi-bin/webapp` page.

Comment: The `CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION` in the initial code is that is causing it to return the redirect to home.html assuming the `login` url is sending back a `Location` header.